# $state.target not working while inside a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application with roles and permission according to which the user will be allowed to navigate throughout the app. However, I am not able to get the $state.target to work in the below code. Note that the `UserService.getUserRole()` fetches the data via $http from the API and is a promise.

**I am Using UI.Router**

```
// States with authorization
$transitions.onStart({ to: statesWithAuth }, function(transition) {
  let isBoss, isManager, isGrunt;
  let nextState = transition.to().data;
  let $state = transition.router.stateService;

  if (AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
    UserService.getUserRole().then(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        isBoss = UserService.isBoss(user.roles);
        isManager = UserService.isManager(user.roles);
        isGrunt = UserService.isGrunt(user.roles);
      }

      // Grunt
      if (isGrunt) {
        if (!nextState.permissions.grunt) {
          return $state.target("workdesk");
        }
      }

      // Manager
      if (isManager) {
        if (!nextState.permissions.manager) {
          return $state.target("workboard");
        }
      }

      // Boss
      if (isBoss) {
        if (!nextState.permissions.boss) {
          return $state.target("relaxingChair");
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Everything works fine until the `!nextState.permissions.*`. After that, the state isn't being transited.

If you have any other ideas on how can I achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: Please open up browser console and see for error log.

Comment: @VipinKumar There are none.

Comment: You can add a debugger and check for any unexpected value.

Comment: @VipinKumar Did that. As I said, `"Everything works fine until the !nextState.permissions.*. After that, the state isn't being transited."`

Comment: Is there any plunker/fiddler link or any public link? where we can take a look?

Comment: @VipinKumar I can only share the `app.run` block with anonymized variable names. Will that be okay?

Comment: If the code that you are going to share is debuggable only share it then. Otherwise you have already shared no debuggable code.

Comment: @VipinKumar Sorry, can't do it then